# Parcel/React App works in localhost but not on server

Tags: reactjs, react-router, localhost, parcel

I have a Parcel/React App that I am attempting to launch to production. After testing, I see that my navigation no longer works on the server (404s).

I'm using React Router like so:

```
<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
  <Router primary={false}>
  <Home path="/" />
  <About path="/about" />
  <Portfolio path="work" />
  <Contact path="/contact" />
  </Router>
</Suspense>
```

I added homepage to my package.json as suggested in another thread, but still no luck.

```
"homepage": "."
```

I don't have any experience with IIS manager or anything like that so I am hesitant to make any server changes there, especially since I have other websites on the same server.

Is there anything that can be done in the code/build to make this work on the server, or will it require IIS changes?

Here is my package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "ericbelldesigns",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Eric Bell Designs 2020",
  "main": "src/App.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@frontendmasters/pet": "^1.0.3",
    "@reach/router": "^1.3.1",
    "anime": "^0.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bezier-easing": "^2.1.0",
    "charming": "^3.0.1",
    "gsap": "^2.1.3",
    "gsap-react-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "imagesloaded": "^4.1.4",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "three": "^0.106.2",
    "three-obj-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "three-orbit-controls": "^82.1.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 Chrome versions",
    "last 2 ChromeAndroid versions",
    "last 2 Firefox versions",
    "last 2 FirefoxAndroid versions",
    "last 2 Safari versions",
    "last 2 iOS versions",
    "last 2 Edge versions",
    "last 2 Opera versions",
    "last 2 OperaMobile versions"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.3",
    "animejs": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.18.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.1",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "parcel-plugin-html-externals": "^0.1.2",
    "postcss-modules": "^1.5.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.0",
    "threejs-controls": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel src/index.html",
    "dev:mock": "cross-env PET_MOCK=mock npm run dev",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --quiet",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "production": "parcel build src/index.html"
  },
  "externals": {
    "/images/**/*": false
  },
  "author": "Eric Bell <eric@ericbelldesigns.com>",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "keywords": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you imported `BrowserRouter` change it to `HashRouter` instead and see if that helps.

Comment: I haven't imported either BrowserRouter or HashRouter.

Comment: Aren't you using an Alias for BrowserRouter? I mean this line: import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";?

Comment: I've used: import { Router } from '@reach/router';

Comment: You're using a Reach Router not a React Router I suggest updating your question with this info. Also, try to use React Router as the one you used is just a simple version of the real thing unless of course there's some constraints you're following

Comment: Yes, you're right. That is my mistake. I'm going to try React Router now per your suggestion. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: BrowserRouter is working for me on the server. Thank you for your help!